# How to correctly query database for results that contain lists

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Say I have a database that contains the following:

```
orders(id, total, address_id)
line_items(id, product_id, order_id, quantity, price)
products(id, name, price)
addresses(id, address)
```

I need to provide a report that contains the following:

```
Order #123
Line Items
  3 x Product 1 @ $3 = $9
  2 x Product 2 @ 1 = $2
Total: $11
Shipping: 123 Main Street

Order #124
Line Items
  1 x Product 1 @ $3 = $3
  1 x Product 2 @ 1 = $1
Total: $4
Shipping: 456 Jones Ave
```

So, a list of orders, for each order, the id, the list of line items, the order total, and the shipping address need to be displayed.

What's the best way to do this without doing a query for each order to fetch the line items and the shipping information?

Should I have a view that contains the following:

```
order_id, line_item_quantity, line_item_price, product_name, line_item_total, shipping_address
```

And then group by order id in the application code?  That's the best I can come up with, but it seems sloppy (and of course, in the real world, there would be much more information in each table and a lot more tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten the relationship, and sort it by order ID:

```
select O.id, L.quantity, P.name, P.price, A.address,
L.quantity * P.price subtotal,
(
    select sum(L1.quantity * P1.price)
    from line_items L1
    inner join products P1 on L1.product_id = P1.id
    where L1.order_id = O.id
) ordertotal
from orders O
inner join line_items L on O.id = L.order_id
inner join products P on L.product_id = P.id
inner join addresses A on O.address_id = A.id
order by O.id, L.id
```

Then depending on how you build your report, try to detect changes in order ID when looping through the resulting rows. When the order ID changes, it is time to set up a new set of order.

For example, if you use crystal reports, you just have to set a new grouping on order ID, and it will automatically segment orders.

Comment: Right, so that's basically what I said -- have a view that lists all the values in a flat table, then use application code that knows how to group it.